# Locked question countdown message is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions

I just noticed this when tending to a locked question:

[image]

I think the wording is a bit skewiff.

Comment: Are there timed-out locks? `:-)`

Comment: *"Dear Next Person Who Opens a Time Message 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant Clock"* - Jeff Atwood

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'll have the kettle on.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old problem, but the underlying issue was almost certainly clock skew that has been fixed in the interim.

Comment: I _knew_ Stack Overflow had a [few screws loose](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a%20few%20screws%20loose)!

Comment: [o rly?](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081218102845/meme/images/thumb/7/73/O_rly.jpg/180px-O_rly.jpg)